Is there a way to find a comment of a deleted post?
This math.se post in the comments of the question has a comment stating "There is a good comment by Henrik Rüping at MO."
Unfortunately the link to the MO post from the question itself has been deleted. See here
Is there any way to recover that deleted comment and/or any other useful content?

High rep users can see deleted questions.  The comment in question contained roughly the same info as Robert Israel’s answer to that math.se question.
